# Connect my Android phone to a WiFi hotspot from my laptop

Tags: wi-fi, custom-roms, linux

I want to connect my rooted HTC Ville to a WiFi hotspot I made with my  laptop, since I don't have WiFi at home. I'm running fedora 20 on my laptop and CM 11 on my HTC One S.

I can see the WEP secured WLAN with my handy but it doesn't connect.

Do you have any ideas why and how to fix it?

Comment: Could it be you're talking about an [ad-hoc-network](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/ad-hoc-networks/info)? That's not natively supported by Android, sorry (see the link for details).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stock Android doesn't support ad-hoc WiFi networks.

If you have a rooted device, it's possible to work around this limitation as described [here](http://szym.net/2010/12/adhoc-wifi-in-android/). Basically you can install a custom ROM that has this feature enabled, or [manually configure](http://www.olsr.org/?q=olsr_on_android) the wpa-supplicant, or if you are feeling adventurous you can compile your own [patched](http://szym.net/android/wpa_supplicant-ibss.patch) copy of wpa-supplicant that fools Android into thinking that ad-hoc networks are regular infrastructure mode access points.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that and hope it helps.
I read that Android can connect to WPA networks but not to WEP ones. After what I read my laptop can only create a WEP hotspot. Is that true?